# Accessing an element inside of a Collectionview datatemplate in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am fairly new to Xamarin.Forms and am attempting to access a child element of a **CollectionView DataTemplate**.

The **DataTemplate** contains a horizontal **StackLayout** consisting of a **Checkbox** and a **Label**.

What I would like to do is to make the **Checkbox**'s `IsChecked` property equal to `true` whenever the **CollectionView** element is selected, in order to show the **Checkbox** as checked when an element is selected.

The highest number of elements that I will ever have in this **CollectionView** are 2.

Here is some code to illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  x:Class="CheckBoxExample.MainPage">

  <StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label
      Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
      HorizontalOptions="Center"
      VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Frame>
      <CollectionView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout
              Orientation="Horizontal">
              <CheckBox
                IsChecked="" />
              <Label
                Text="{Binding .}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
          </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      </CollectionView>
    </Frame>

  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: why don't you just use the ItemSelected event to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check a **CheckBox** whenever it is selected, and uncheck it when it is unselected, and assuming, as you mentioned, that you will only have two items, the following code should put you on the right track:

---

First, We define our model in the following way

```
public class Costumer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _Text;
    public String Text
    {
        get => _Text;
        set
        {
            if (_Text != value)
            {
                _Text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private Boolean _Checked;
    public Boolean IsChecked
    {
        get => _Checked;
        set
        {
            if (_Checked != value)
            {
                _Checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}

public class Costumers : List<Costumer>,  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Costumer _CostumerSelected;
    public Costumer CostumerSelected
    {
        get => _CostumerSelected;
        set
        {
            if (_CostumerSelected != value)
            {
                if (_CostumerSelected!=null) _CostumerSelected.IsChecked = false;
                _CostumerSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                _CostumerSelected.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In the previous code, note what is going on in the `CostumerSelected` setter: If the selection changed, and an item is already selected, it is unchecked. After that, the new selected item is checked.

Then in the **XAML**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Frame >
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding CostumerSelected}"
                            SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

In the code above, note that i assigned the `SelectionMode` property, in order to allow selection! Also, i bound the `SelectedItem` property to the `CostumerSelected` in my **Costumers** Model.

And in the code behind, we simply populate the **CollectionView**:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    BindingContext = new Costumers() { new Costumer() { Text = "James Sku" }, new Costumer() { Text = "Daniel Gomez" } };

    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible doing anything similar but without changing the model "Customer"? Like binding IsChecked to "check checkbox at current selectedItem index"

Comment: Actually, when xamarin forms v4.5 release, we will be having VisualStateManager Target. CollectionView has Selected state, set a Target and do stuff. It will be released soon. Early feb

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/visual-state-manager/